# vinsol-spree-contrib/shopspree-sales-app Installation error

Tags: ruby-on-rails, rake, spree, chewy-gem

After Cloning the [ShopSpree Sales](https://github.com/vinsol-spree-contrib/shopspree-sales-app) I followed the installation instructions and almost worked fine except `bundle exec rake spree_sample:load`. It gives me the following error :

```
asdf08:~/workspace (master) $ bundle exec rake spree_sample:load
Loaded Payment Methods samples
Loaded Shipping Categories samples
Loaded Shipping Methods samples
Loaded Tax Categories samples
Loaded Tax Rates samples
rake aborted!
Chewy::UndefinedUpdateStrategy: Index update strategy is undefined in current context.
Please wrap your code with `Chewy.strategy(:strategy_name) block.`
/usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.0/gems/chewy-0.8.3/lib/chewy/strategy/base.rb:17:in `update'
/usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.0/gems/chewy-0.8.3/lib/chewy/type/observe.rb:70:in `update_index'
/usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.0/gems/chewy-0.8.3/lib/chewy/type/observe.rb:28:in `block in update_proc'
/usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.0/gems/activesupport-4.2.4/lib/active_support/callbacks.rb:446:in `instance_exec'
/usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.0/gems/activesupport-4.2.4/lib/active_support/callbacks.rb:446:in `block in make_lambda'
/usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.0/gems/activesupport-4.2.4/lib/active_support/callbacks.rb:263:in `block in simple'
/usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.0/gems/activesupport-4.2.4/lib/active_support/callbacks.rb:506:in `block in call'
/usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.0/gems/activesupport-4.2.4/lib/active_support/callbacks.rb:506:in `each'
/usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.0/gems/activesupport-4.2.4/lib/active_support/callbacks.rb:506:in `call'
/usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.0/gems/activesupport-4.2.4/lib/active_support/callbacks.rb:92:in `__run_callbacks__'
/usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.0/gems/activesupport-4.2.4/lib/active_support/callbacks.rb:778:in `_run_commit_callbacks'
/usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.0/gems/activerecord-4.2.4/lib/active_record/transactions.rb:314:in `committed!'
/usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.0/gems/activerecord-4.2.4/lib/active_record/connection_adapters/abstract/transaction.rb:89:in `commit_records'
/usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.0/gems/activerecord-4.2.4/lib/active_record/connection_adapters/abstract/transaction.rb:153:in `commit'
/usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.0/gems/activerecord-4.2.4/lib/active_record/connection_adapters/abstract/transaction.rb:175:in `commit_transaction'
/usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.0/gems/activerecord-4.2.4/lib/active_record/connection_adapters/abstract/transaction.rb:194:in `within_new_transaction'
/usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.0/gems/activerecord-4.2.4/lib/active_record/connection_adapters/abstract/database_statements.rb:213:in `transaction'
/usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.0/gems/activerecord-4.2.4/lib/active_record/transactions.rb:220:in `transaction'
/usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.0/gems/activerecord-4.2.4/lib/active_record/transactions.rb:348:in `with_transaction_returning_status'
/usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.0/gems/activerecord-4.2.4/lib/active_record/transactions.rb:291:in `save!'
/usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.0/gems/activerecord-4.2.4/lib/active_record/persistence.rb:51:in `create!'
/usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.0/bundler/gems/spree-a275c9db4f0c/sample/db/samples/products.rb:129:in `block in <top (required)>'
/usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.0/bundler/gems/spree-a275c9db4f0c/sample/db/samples/products.rb:124:in `each'
/usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.0/bundler/gems/spree-a275c9db4f0c/sample/db/samples/products.rb:124:in `<top (required)>'
/usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.0/gems/polyglot-0.3.5/lib/polyglot.rb:65:in `require'
/usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.0/gems/polyglot-0.3.5/lib/polyglot.rb:65:in `require'
/usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.0/gems/activesupport-4.2.4/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:274:in `block in require'
/usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.0/gems/activesupport-4.2.4/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:240:in `load_dependency'
/usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.0/gems/activesupport-4.2.4/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:274:in `require'
/usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.0/bundler/gems/spree-a275c9db4f0c/sample/lib/spree/sample.rb:13:in `load_sample'
/usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.0/bundler/gems/spree-a275c9db4f0c/sample/lib/spree_sample.rb:16:in `load_samples'
/usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.0/bundler/gems/spree-a275c9db4f0c/sample/lib/tasks/sample.rake:20:in `block (2 levels) in <top (required)>'
/usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.0/gems/bundler-1.13.6/lib/bundler/cli/exec.rb:74:in `load'
/usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.0/gems/bundler-1.13.6/lib/bundler/cli/exec.rb:74:in `kernel_load'
/usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.0/gems/bundler-1.13.6/lib/bundler/cli/exec.rb:27:in `run'
/usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.0/gems/bundler-1.13.6/lib/bundler/cli.rb:332:in `exec'
/usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.0/gems/bundler-1.13.6/lib/bundler/vendor/thor/lib/thor/command.rb:27:in `run'
/usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.0/gems/bundler-1.13.6/lib/bundler/vendor/thor/lib/thor/invocation.rb:126:in `invoke_command'
/usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.0/gems/bundler-1.13.6/lib/bundler/vendor/thor/lib/thor.rb:359:in `dispatch'
/usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.0/gems/bundler-1.13.6/lib/bundler/cli.rb:20:in `dispatch'
/usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.0/gems/bundler-1.13.6/lib/bundler/vendor/thor/lib/thor/base.rb:440:in `start'
/usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.0/gems/bundler-1.13.6/lib/bundler/cli.rb:11:in `start'
/usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.0/gems/bundler-1.13.6/exe/bundle:34:in `block in <top (required)>'
/usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.0/gems/bundler-1.13.6/lib/bundler/friendly_errors.rb:100:in `with_friendly_errors'
/usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.0/gems/bundler-1.13.6/exe/bundle:26:in `<top (required)>'
/usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.0/bin/bundle:23:in `load'
/usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.0/bin/bundle:23:in `<main>'
/usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.0/bin/ruby_executable_hooks:15:in `eval'
/usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.0/bin/ruby_executable_hooks:15:in `<main>'
Tasks: TOP => spree_sample:load
(See full trace by running task with --trace)
```

However I tried starting rail server and It gives me something like below without any styles.I think the page is not completely loaded.

[image]

And when I try to login with given credentials in creating admin user db:seed
It keep on displaying **You have to confirm your account before continuing.**
Giving invalid credentials shows me **Invalid email or password.** So that means nothing wrong with my credentials here.

I know this app is back-end api for [Spree Android App](https://github.com/vinsol-spree-contrib/spree-android).

Any help would be appreciable in this matter. Thank you.

Comment: I presume you created, migrated and seeded the db?

Comment: yes.. in the exact order..

Answer (score 0):

looks like you have some configs to attend to in chewy. Look here: https://github.com/toptal/chewy

Comment: I m completely new to these frameworks and dependencies. Can you explain it further please. What kind of configs ??

Comment: OK. You'll have to read the information on the link where the chewy gem is hosted. There are some settting that are required, and it looks like your error has to do with that. I would recommend some simpler introductory Rails apps before attempting to wire up an e-commerce app. That would get you comfortable with dependencies, gems and the like. I hate to see you get bogged down before you even get started.

Comment: Actually the main purpose to install is , this app works as a back-end api of an android application (Spree Android App.)  So it is essential to install and config this app to work with it.